# Why does the number of sql queries count incorrectly?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I want to get sql query counter variable in YII in main config. But sometimes the unexplainable happens and they are not taken into account using `Yii:getLogger()->getDbProfilng()[0];`
**With what it can be connected?**

The event used is `afterAction`.
Soo..

[image]
[image]

I thought about getting it directly from Yii::getLogger() via an array, but it turns out to be 127 requests...

```
$messages = Yii::getLogger()->messages;

$countQueries = 0;
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    if (is_array($message) && isset($message[2]) && $message[2] === 'yii\db\Command::query') {
        $countQueries++;
    }
}
echo $countQueries;
```

Comment: If caching is enabled, temporarily disable it to see if that affects the query count.

Comment: @talha2k
so.. ```Yii::$app->cache->flush();``` is not working

Comment: `yii\log\Logger::getDbProfiling()` only returns info about db profilling among current log messages. If the log messages were already flushed they are not included.